# Reference needed for effective gravitational potential in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, potential, potential-energy, specific-reference

In Wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity ) one can find the following expression for the effective gravitational potential in the Schwarzschild approximation

$$V(r)=-\frac{GMm}{r}+\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}-\frac{G(M+m)L^2}{c^2\mu r^3}$$

This is given without reference. Does anybody know a citable reference (i.e. from a peer-reviewed journal or textbook) that gives the relativistic term in this or a closely similar form?

I am not interested in a further discussion or derivation here, just a citable reference.

Comment: The book by Wald provides the formula in a form close to that one.

Comment: Isn't this done in pretty much every introductory textbook in General Relativity?